# How to avoid sub2ind and decrease execution time in manipulating multidimensional arrays using original indexes

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing

I would like your suggestions to make my code faster (and elegant). In particular, sub2ind (and the if-loop) slow it down dramatically according to the matlab profiler. I will try to explain what I need from my code as simply as I can.

Assuming I have the following problem, for simplicity.

Every citizen of every city has a car of a specific brand and a specific color. 
What I would like to have is a 4D multidimensional array `Data_4D(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color)` that I can manipulate (read and modify) using as indexes only these four dimensions.

Then, I want to reshape my multidimensional array into a 1D array Data_1D with

```
length(Data_1D)=(City*Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color)
```

The order of the elements must follow an indexing rule: 
Example assuming `City=2, Citizen=2, Car_brand=2, Car_color=2`;

```
    Data_1D(1)=Data_4D(1,1,1,1)
    Data_1D(2)=Data_4D(1,1,1,2)
    Data_1D(3)=Data_4D(1,1,2,1)
    Data_1D(4)=Data_4D(1,1,2,2)
    Data_1D(5)=Data_4D(1,2,1,1)
    Data_1D(6)=Data_4D(1,2,1,2)
    Data_1D(7)=Data_4D(1,2,2,1)
    Data_1D(8)=Data_4D(1,2,2,2)
    Data_1D(9)=Data_4D(2,1,1,1)
    Data_1D(10)=Data_4D(2,1,1,2)
    Data_1D(11)=Data_4D(2,1,2,1)
    Data_1D(12)=Data_4D(2,1,2,2)
    Data_1D(13)=Data_4D(2,2,1,1)
    Data_1D(14)=Data_4D(2,2,1,2)
    Data_1D(15)=Data_4D(2,2,2,1)
    Data_1D(16)=Data_4D(2,2,2,2)
```

After that I will get this 1D array, shaped as above, I need to create a matrix `Matrix_Final( NRows,length(Data_1D))` in which every row is an array Data_1D. In every row NRows, the array Data_1D will have the same amount of elements but with different values.
The amount of rows depends also on some (or all) of the four the dimensions City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color (respecting the same indexing rule as for Data_1D) and the array built in each line must be manipulated according also to the value of the matrix row (by using the four indexes, which is the common rule for both NRows and Data_1D).

Example: 
Assuming `City=2, Citizen=2, Car_brand=2, Car_color=2`;
Assuming **NRows depends on all the four dimensions**.
I will have `Matrix_Final( length(DATA_1D), length(DATA_1D))`.
I want that all the data of my array DATA_1D are zeros, except one element, which has to be the element that has the same indexes values`(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color)` as `NRows(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color)`
So at the row `NRows(1)`, only `Data_1D(1)` is non-zero. For this example, the result is an eye matrix.

```
clc
  clear all
  %Dimensions Definition
  City=2;
  Citizen=2;
  Car_brand=2;
  Car_color=2;
  %Length of Data
  Length_Data_1D=City*Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color;
  %preallocation Matrix_Final
  Matrix_Final=zeros(City*Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color, Length_Data_1D);
  %indexes of the dimensions
  indexes_array_carcolor=repmat(repelem([1:Car_color], 1), [1 City*Citizen*Car_brand]);
  indexes_array_carbrand=repmat(repelem([1:Car_brand], Car_color), [1 City*Citizen]);
  indexes_array_citizen=repmat(repelem([1:Citizen],Car_brand*Car_color),[1 City]);
  indexes_array_city=repmat(repelem([1:City],Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color),[1 1]);
  %Initializing loop variable
  column_Matrix_final=1;

  for CITY_selected=1:City
     for CITIZEN_selected=1:Citizen 
         for CAR_BRAND_selected=1:Car_brand
           for CAR_COLOR_selected=1:Car_color
            %Data_4D Construction
            Data_4D=zeros(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color);
              for city=1:length(indexes_array_city)
                for citizen=1:length(indexes_array_citizen)
                    for car_brand=1:length(indexes_array_carbrand)
                        for car_color=1:length(indexes_array_carcolor)
                            if (indexes_array_city(city)==CITY_selected && indexes_array_citizen(citizen)==CITIZEN_selected ...
                                  && indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand)==CAR_BRAND_selected && ...
                                  indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==CAR_COLOR_selected)
                          Data_4D(sub2ind(size(Data_4D),indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
                              indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)))=1; 
                            end
                      end
                  end
              end
       end
      %Data_4D transformation into array Data_1D
      Data_1D=zeros(1,City*Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color);
      tic=1;
      for city=1:City
          for citizen=1:Citizen
              for car_brand=1:Car_brand
                  for car_color=1:Car_color
                      Data_1D(tic)=Data_4D(city,citizen,car_brand,car_color);
                      tic=tic+1;
                  end
              end
          end
      end
      %Adding Data_1D to the next for of Matrix_Final
      Matrix_Final(column_Matrix_final,:)=Data_1D;
      column_Matrix_final=column_Matrix_final+1;
      %Display of the four most external loops indexes to show code
      %advancement
       CAR_COLOR_selected
     end
         CAR_BRAND_selected
  end
      CITIZEN_selected
 end
         CITY_selected 
end
      spy(Matrix_Final)
```

If you add e.g.

```
  && indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==2
```

in the if loop, only the elements of `Data_1D(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color=2)` in `NRows(City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color=2)` will be non-zero.

I would like to know if there are faster ways to set up the problem, but keeping the same ability to manipulate Data_1D an Matrix_Final using the four indexes (City,Citizen,Car_brand,Car_color) and the ability to correlate NRows and the elements of Data_1D using these four indexes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you use `sub2ind` there : `Data_4D(sub2ind(size(Data_4D),indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
                              indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)))=1;` I guess 
`Data_4D(indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
                              indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color))=1;` would yield the exact same result

Comment: I don't understand the way you create you matrix `Data_4D` neither, seems like you are overwriting a  lot of times the same index to 1

Comment: Won't the result always be the eye matrix?

Comment: I think your code doesn't do what you want it to do. For a given `(City,Citizen)`, you might want to draw only one `Car_Brand` and only one `Car_Color`

Comment: @BillBokeey: Thank you for your answer.  Every citizen can have multiple cars with every color (also same car with different colors).

Comment: Okay. However, the way you code works for now will assign avery car color and every car brand to every citizen in every city, thus giving you the eye matrix everytime

Comment: @BillBokeey Regarding how I build `Data_4D`: I do not think I am overwriting values. I am building the multidimensional array element-by-element within the four for-loops with indexes `city`, `citizen`, `car_brand`, `car_color`. 
Then, `Data_4D` is reshaped into `Data_1D` and added as a row in `Matrix_Final`. 
Then, another `Data_4D` is build to be added to the next row of `Matrix_Final`. This happens within the four external for-loops with indexes `CITY_selected`, `CITIZEN_selected`, `CAR_BRAND_selected`, `CAR_COLOR_selected`.

Comment: @BillBokeey Concerning the use of `sub2ind`, in this example it does the same. I have to admit that I am not an expert in its use. I do not know if it will be the same in every case that I will have to face.

Comment: Well, it will indeed, except if you change your code. For now, your code will ALWAYS result in the eye matrix, thus my comment

Comment: @BillBokeey I will have to change my code for e.g. by adding constraints in the if loop (e.g. 1), or if `NRows` does not depend on all the four dimensions (e.g. 2).

e.g. 1. As already mentioned, just by simply adding `&& indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==2` in the if cycle.

e.g. 2. I can say that `NRows` depends only on `City` and `Citizen`. Thereby the for-loops for `CAR_BRAND_selected` and  `CAR_COLOR_selected` will be deleted. It will result in `Matrix_Final(City*Citizen, length(DATA_1D))` in which `Citizen=1` of `City=1` in NRows(1) will have all the cars of all the colors, and so on.

Comment: You should really write one code that will adapt to every situation..

Comment: If somehow you end with MATLAB code that has 8 nested loops there is a single and unique conclusions you should get to: You code structure sucks, and you need to rethink, and redo it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you for your comment. This is why I am posting a question about improving code performance. If someone suggests me how to avoid for loops in my code as much as possible, I would be more than glad to accept his/her suggestions.

Comment: John, you first need to think about what you really want your code to do (for now, as I said, it's equivalent to `column_Matrix_final=eye(City*Citizen*Car_brand*Car_color);`
Which is, though, a great improvment in calculation speed

Comment: @BillBokeey Maybe I have done a mistake in setting the example code to result in an eye matrix, because it oversimplifies the problem. 
I want my code to build `Data_4D`(and as a consequence `Data_1D`) with non-zero elements based on every possible constraint that can be written in terms of the four dimensions 'City' 'Citizen' `Car_brand` `Car_color` . e.g. All elements of `City=1`, `Citizen=5` are non zero. All elements with `Car_color=2` are non zero.
Moreover, I want to be able to impose non zero elements also according to the row of `Matrix_Final` which is related to the same dimensions.

Comment: My final advice will be : Close this question, delete all your code, rethink your problem by answering the question : "what do I really want to do". I'll gladly help when you'll have a real question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you have coded it

```
if (indexes_array_city(city)==CITY_selected && indexes_array_citizen(citizen)==CITIZEN_selected ...
     && indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand)==CAR_BRAND_selected && ...
   indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==CAR_COLOR_selected)
   Data_4D(sub2ind(size(Data_4D),indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
   indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)))=1; 
end
```

Another way 1

```
if (indexes_array_city(city)==CITY_selected && indexes_array_citizen(citizen)==CITIZEN_selected ...
     && indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand)==CAR_BRAND_selected && ...
    indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==CAR_COLOR_selected)
    Data_4D(indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
    indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color))=1; 
end
```

Another way 2

```
Data_4D(indexes_array_city(city),indexes_array_citizen(citizen),...
     indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand), indexes_array_carcolor(car_color))=double((indexes_array_city(city)==CITY_selected)& ...
                                  (indexes_array_citizen(citizen)==CITIZEN_selected)& ...
                                  (indexes_array_carbrand(car_brand)==CAR_BRAND_selected)& ...
                                  (indexes_array_carcolor(car_color)==CAR_COLOR_selected));
```

All three of them will yield same result. Try which is faster and use it.

```
%% Data_4D transformation into array Data_1D
Data_4D_size=size(Data_4D);
Data_1D_size=prod(Data_4D_size);
temp = permute(Data_4D, [4 3 2 1]);
Data_1D=reshape(temp,Data_1D_size,1);
```

Use this for 4D to 1D convertion

> If still need more speed. Compile it to mex. Compiled code runs faster.